# I want to implement Key Listener on jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, keylistener

I have added JLabel on my JFrame object. I want to implement a key listener on JLabel. Can I implement it? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: You cannot do that. See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594461/add-keylistener-to-jlabel

Comment: KeyListener isn't focusable JComponents, not desiganted for this idea, KeyListener isn't implemented in JLabels API

Comment: Forget what you want for a moment.  What feature are you attempting to provide the user?  This sounds like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Comment: What do you want to do with that Listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not want to add a `KeyListener` on a `JLabel`. It would be better if you would add it to the `JFrame`.
Supposing you have the following code structure, then it should work:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private JLabel jLab;
    //...fields, getters, setters whatever...
    private int i;
    public MyFrame()
    {
        i = 0;
        jLab = new JLabel("Example");
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                //doSomething(); - this may create confusion.
            }
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
                //doSomething(); - this may create confusion.
            }
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
                doSomething();
            }
        });
        add(jLab);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        i++;
        jLab.setText(i + "");
    }
}
```

And, don't forget to `import`!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

---

RESULT: when you create a new `MyFrame` in the `main()` method. This is what you see at first:

[image: Starting]

After five random key-strokes,

[image: After 5]

Comment: Please make sure posted code actually compiles.  That doesn't, even with imports.

Comment: please to delete this answer, JLabel (and JFrame) can't receive any KeyEvents, simple isn't fosusable, then can't react to KeyEvents

Comment: `public MyFrame extends JFrame {`  -> `error: class, interface, or enum expected`

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oops! :-) And thanks for the help. Now it fully compiles and works correctly.

Comment: This will work for Frame not for lable what if there are more than one lable???No use of this...

Comment: @TAsk Well, then we'd have to add a detection mechanism of ___which key is pressed___ and call various methods separately. One ***can*** use ***as many `JLabel`s*** as he/she want's.

Answer (score 2):

Guess I'm a bit too late but calling `label.requestFocus();` after adding the `key listener` to the `label` works for me!

Answer (score 1):

**Key events are fired by the component with the keyboard focus when the user presses or releases keyboard keys.**

*BUT JLabel is not one of those components.*